# Form.show() method shows error

Tags: vb.net

I have been doing some searching around and seem to only be coming up with folks who were trying to convert a string to an integer and not my particular situation. My code was working wonderfully till earlier today and all of a sudden is throwing this error and I can not figure out why.

```
    Private Sub loadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loadButton.Click
    If systemBox.Text = "" Or managementBox.Text = "" Or profileBox.Text = "" Or batchNumBox.Text = "" Then
        requestTypeBox.Text = ""
        MsgBox("Not all required fields selected. Please select a value from each box.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim requestValue As String
    requestValue = requestTypeBox.SelectedItem

    Select Case requestValue
        Case "Financials"
            financialsForm.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case "Stop Mail"
            stopMailForm.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case "Dividends"
            dividendsForm.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case "Stop Purchase/Transfer"
            stopPurchTrans.Show()
            Me.Hide()
    End Select
End Sub
```

I get the following error on the financialsForm.Show() line and none of the other similar lines in this code."Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." As you can see there is no converting going on. All other forms load fine. I have been going at this for a while today and am a bit stumped. I had removed some code from my select case statement already that had been showing the same error and yet it keeps erroring out in that particular select case selection. It all seems to boil down to something with the financialsForm but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. `requestTypeBox.SelectedItem` is Object.  Depending on what is in that thing, it may be an integer boxed as Object, thus the error on `Case "Financials"`
`

Comment: Also be aware, you will probably get more errors  It is worth it to take the time to fix them, will help in preventing weird hard to find bugs.

Comment: My bad. I had removed the code that was throwing the error previously with my original headline and forgot to update the headline. So it's not a string to string issue. Apologies. It's the just the financialsForm.Show() throwing the error.

Comment: Same advice - the real error is likely on the preceding line.  `requestValue = requestTypeBox.SelectedItem` wont compile under `Option Strict`

Comment: The other three forms in the select case statement load correctly using the same code. I don't think that line is the issue. The requestTypeBox is populated only with the four strings you see in the select case. I have used the same assignment type logic a lot in this project and have not had any issues.

Comment: Maybe it is in that form constructor or maybe form load.  Either way somewhere you are trying to convert an empty string to an integer (`"Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid."`)  Same advice: turn on Option Strict - the compiler will find it (and other too most likely).

Comment: I think I just found my problem. Looks like I made a mistake when I was assigning some values in this long list of variables in the financialsForm. Thanks for the help @Plutonix

Comment: Always have "optoin strict on" and "option infer off" it will make you a better coder in the long run.